# installing tomcat and full kit of j2ee on windows 7

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, netbeans

I want to install apache tomcat server latest version on my windows7. I don have any kit for the further action. where do and how do i download the kit and how to install them? Please give me the step by step procedure. as well as i want to install j2ee kit netbeans etc. please give me the details. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Apache tomcat, you have to select what version. In some companies are still using 5.5 as standard.:
http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

java2ee:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html

Netbeans:
http://netbeans.org/features/web/index.html

Alternatively to Netbeans I recommend eclipse for development. There is a version specific for j2ee:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/